# FBSTP store wrong value

Tags: assembly, fpu

I am writing a program that calculate arctan function.
 Function that does all work works fine, but when i try get bcd-value fbstp command store weird value and fstp store right value.

```
segment data 
result:  resb 10
tmp_val: dd 000000000h
precs:   dq 03a83126fh ; 0.001
arg:     dd 03f800000h ; 0.7

segment code
..start:

mov ax,data
mov ds, ax
finit

call calc_value
fst dword[tmp_val]
fbstp tword [result]

mov ax, 4C00h
int 21h
```

And after execution in memory
at tmp_val: 0x3f490edb (0.785383)
and at result: 0x0000000000000000001

And i write this for DOS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The intel instruction set reference says this for `fbstp`:

> If the source value is a non-integral value, it is rounded to an
>   integer value, according to rounding mode specified by the RC field of
>   the FPU control word.

As such, a result of 1 sounds right.

Comment: Oh. I am so stupid =_= 
Hmmm. And then how to print float values?

Comment: This might not be the most efficient way, but you could split to integer and fractional part, print the integer, then multiply the fractional part by 10^n (where n is the number of digits you want) and print that after a decimal point (with the appropriate amount of leading and trailing zeroes). *Actually you don't even need to split, just multiply before the `fbstp` and then place the decimal point appropriately.